# Django admin on the frontend

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I'm still in the process of learning the basics of Django. I have a lot of questions. But the biggest one at the moment is to understand how I *reuse* admin **models**, **forms** and **templates** to display it on the frontend instead by going on the backend admin control panel.

What I've done so far is to create a url in `urls.py`, created a view in `views.py` and added template path, created the template.

Everything works well with that. But how do I just "copy" the admin model that I want so the user that is logged in can **edit** on the frontend instead?

What do I need to look more into to understand this so I can implement the admin on the frontend?

Comment: if i understand well, you need to register models in admin.py, and then you can edit in `/admin`

Comment: No, I don't want to register models. The model is already registered. I don't want to be using the `/admin`. I want to use the frontpage as the admin panel. E.g. adding the user list from `/admin` to `index.html` so I as a super user or staff member can control it from there. Do you understand want I asking for? @Baterson

Comment: so your need to create form based on your model, and then add this form in view and template.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Though the admin can be configured through a permission system it is nothing that should be exposed to your front end users - it only should be used by users you can fully trust (administrators).

To implement similar functionality on the frontend look into Django's [`ModelForms`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/modelforms/#modelform) and [Generic Views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/) which should help you to implement simple CRUD actions rather quickly. If you would like to implement a Javascript based frontend something like [Django-REST-Framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/) might be a good choice to implement something similar for a REST-API.

Nonetheless you could still add a [second `AdminSite`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/admin/#multiple-admin-sites-in-the-same-urlconf) to your project - but as stated above this is not really recommended for security reasons, if you would expose it to the "normal" user.

Comment: Ok, I understand your point. But I've seen tons of webapps that use this method to their users so they can use settings for their app. So how can it be done securly?